# I can't find the OpenID delete button

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

I have two OpenID accounts. So what I want to do is delete or remove my private email from the StackExchange OpenId, but the problem is I can't find the remove, delete or deactivate button?

I want to remove my private email from OpenID because I only use that email for my family, friends and love ones.

Comment: Also I think the process to remove a Stack Exchange OpenID account requires you to use the [contact form](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have a self-serve way to do that. The normal process is to contact us via the link at the bottom of any page on any site.

In your case, I removed the OpenID associated with your private email address.

I'm also going to remove the screenshots and parts of the question here that reveal your email addresses publicly.

Comment: Thank you for removing my private email address. I'm really appreciate you doings.