# Is an account merge a valid work around to have Two-Factor Authentication in my account?

Tags: support, login

I log into my SE account with SE. And I read that they won't be adding support for 2FA. But there's no article informing a work around for the people who signed up with SE in the first place.

First I thought I could [add a login](https://stackexchange.com/users/login) with a site supporting 2FA and remove the SE login. But there's no way to remove the first login.
[Apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) there was a way to remove logins but it's not working.

So my last hope is I can create another SE account and sign up with a site supporting 2FA, and then follow the [merge procedure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and hope that they leave the second account's login as the only one (something I'm not sure will happen).

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me. I hope I'm not seeing something and there's a much more simpler solution.

Comment: There isn't and won't be 2FA in SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230490/two-factor-authentication-for-stack-exchange and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256767/if-we-built-two-factor-authentication-for-stack-exchange-openid-would-you-use-i?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Pretty sure I managed to remove my SE login in the past.  It was an epic pain to add back, sure ... but should be doable

Comment: @ShadowWizard You are not understanding my question. :)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I checked lots of times and can't see the option of remove SE login. And why did you added it back later?

Comment: @pabvid I did, otherwise I would have closed it as dupe. My comment was meant as "I don't think there is much hope, since there isn't and won't be 2FA support in SE".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for not closing it as dupe! haha But I'm not asking SE to support 2FA, I'm asking if there's a work around for the ones who signed up with SE.

Comment: hmm... regarding removing SE OpenID: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242496/i-cant-find-the-openid-delete-button.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh that's useful! Thank you very much! So contacting SE would be the way to do it, right?

Comment: @pabvid that is true. Glad to help!

Comment: If nothing else, you need to contact them anyway, and it'll get you what you need.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I answered my own question giving the credit to you. Hope that is OK with you.

Comment: try if https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/259430 works for you (that's your user number). If it works, I'll post an answer ;p

Comment: When SE support answers my contact inquiry and I verify [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304270/is-an-account-merge-a-valid-work-around-to-have-two-factor-authentication-in-my/304271#304271) is correct I will add a [NO] prefix to the title of the question, so it doesn't confuse people who read it fast without detention. I'm awaiting. Would it be right to add that prefix??

Comment: @pabvid Don’t do that.  Your edits will be reverted.  You should not use the question title one that capacity.  Guaranteed way of getting a moderator attention and not in a good way

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the way to do it. The way should be to contact SE via the link at the bottom of any page on any site and ask them to remove the SE login.

Source:
[I can't find the OpenID delete button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242496/i-cant-find-the-openid-delete-button)

Credit: @ShadowWizard