# How can I delete one of my associated logins?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

I recently changed email providers, as of today, because I can no longer access my old email account. I somehow managed to associate a second login to my account.

**I want to delete the previous login** and here is where the confusion starts for me. I went to the 'Edit Profile & Settings' page and this is what I got:

[image]

The original login that I want to remove is the second in the list. Obviously there is the option properly titled 'remove' which should remove the associated login.

My question is, if I click on remove will that also delete all of the associated information with the respective login (including the associated password) or will it just dissociate the login from the account? What I would like is to **delete the associated login** and not just remove it from my logins. Just to be clear if still needed, I do not want to delete my account.

I'm a little confused when it comes to the nature of the logins. To be more precise, I don't know if they are OpenID or 'Stack Exchange (aka email/PW)' logins. The quotation marks are used because that is the term I found in this post:

[Support for OpenID ends on July 1, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018).

If I go to the login page (https://openid.stackexchange.com), I can login using either of the two email addresses. But if I look at the 'Edit Profile & Settings' page there it says 'Stack Exchange', so I'm more inclined to believe that the logins are in fact 'Stack Exchange (aka email/PW)'.

Comment: You have two Stack Exchange logins, probably you used different email for each. Removing one won't affect the other, and won't delete anything from your Stack Exchange profile.

Comment: From your answer, I think I was not that clear with my question.  I want to remove and delete one of the logins, not just remove it. Maybe that's exactly what the remove button does, I don't know.  I'm insisting on removing and deleting because from my limited understanding removing would just no longer allow me to sign in using that login, however the information pertaining to it, i.e. e-mail address and password, to still be around somewhere on a server. I want that login to be completely gone.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242496/i-cant-find-the-openid-delete-button

Comment: @andreibarbos not sure that there's anything you can do about info stored on the server. Read the [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) and the [terms and conditions](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) to see what happens to your private info.